# Asking recruiter to reply on job interview right away instead of waiting

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, human-resources

I had my second (and last) interview at a company two days ago. The recruiter had told me in advance that I would get the answer the day after and in case they decided I was a good fit, they would ask for contact info of my references.

The recruiter called me and said that they needed a few more days to decide and they would contact me at the end of the week (Friday afternoon, to be exact).

I have a hunch that they already know that they want to reject me and that they are waiting a few days to give me the message in order to give the impression that they thought long and hard about it and to avoid showing disrespect for a fairly long and intensive interview process. This is in particular because next week is a national holiday, so even if they ask for my references, it will be delayed and it would be in their interest to ask for my references asap in case the answer is positive...

Therefore, is it OK for me to contact the recruiter and let them know that they don't have to wait a few days to give me the negative answer in case they have already decided?

Comment: On your last sentence: what would be your benefit in doing so? None. Just wait and see what they decide. Don't make assumptions.

Comment: Why would company need to make you feel like they have taken the time to consider you unsuitable for the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> have a hunch that they already know that they want to reject me and that they are waiting a few days to give me the message in order to give the impression that they thought long and hard about it and to avoid showing disrespect for a fairly long and intensive interview process.

Or maybe, just maybe they have a couple of candidates they like and need a few days to decide? Why second guess what you think they might be doing? I get that waiting to hear back can be frustrating but I think you need to take a deep breath or ten and relax.

> Therefore, is it OK for me to contact the recruiter and let them know that they don't have to wait a few days to give me the negative answer in case they have already decided?

Yeah, don't do this.. Literally the *only* way this benefits you at all is if you they **are** doing exactly what you think they are doing and are prepared to admit that. Which is crazy talk. If they are still genuinely considering your application (as they have told you they are) then you're going to come off as lacking in self-confidence, impatient, possibly rude and likely a bit weird as well. It certainly has no way of enhancing your chances so you really don't have anything to gain by doing it. So don't.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to read this....

Answer (score 6):

**Don't assume all that**

Hiring is a badly organized part of most businesses. They literally could have forgotten to hold the meeting to decide on the candidate to hire. I've had interviewers forget they scheduled something with me.

My friend worked at a company where HR hired the same job 4 times because whenever the HR assistant managing that job left, everything they did was lost and a tech firm was busy raiding their HR staff. Seriously, they had picked out a candidate to award the job to 4 times and each time they failed to try and hire that candidate. A few weeks later, they got a notification from their system saying that new resumes had arrived and restarted the process. This went on for 6 months until they hired someone.

You are assuming a bad outcome for something that can be explained by incompetence.

Comment: I'd not even necessarily go for incompetence. One of the other interviewees might have needed to postpone their interview and the company might be fair enough (and wanting to get all the options) to give them the additional time for a second attempt. They might have an "emergency" where one of the people involved doesn't get the time to handle the interview etc. Point being there can be all kinds of reasons.